# surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS) is deprecated

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I am capturing video using MediaRecorder. The part of the code is given below.

```
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

But `surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);` is deprecated. Is there any other methods instead of this method. I want to run my code in all versions.

Comment: surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS) was depricated from api level 11 but i have also made an app using it but it works in 4.0 and 4.1 Android OS ,I was also searching for an alternative but was not successful

Comment: May later will get some problems

Comment: The value is set automatically when needed. That is what document says for android. But if it is less than honeycomb then you should set it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the SDK version and only call `SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)` for older versions.

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```